# Tefillas Haderech in Shacharis

Tags: travel, blessing, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer

I once heard of a concept of saying tefillas Haderech in שמע קולינו during shemonah esrei by Shacharis of that day. Has anyone here heard of it, and if so, what's it about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tefilas HaDerech has a Bracha only at the end - there are those that eat something and make a Bracha Achrona first and then immediately say Tefilas HaDerech. Alternatively some people say it in Shemoana Esrei at Shema Koleinu.

טור או"ח סימן ק"י בשם ר"מ מרוטנברג כשהיה יוצא לדרך בבוקר היה אומר תפלת הדרך אחר "הגומל חסדים טובים

Comment: But aren't you supposed to say it at a certain time (e.g. outside city limits)

Comment: I guess there are different interpretations of the law. The question was not as to when it is more proper to say Tefilas HaDerech where I think most Poskim say outside city limits. It was regarding this Minhag of saying it by Davening and why is it done like that by those who do.

Comment: When you are away from home and travelling further, you are already on the way and can say Tefillas HaDerekh in the city.

Comment: It might be considered a *safek* (halachic uncertainty) to say *tefillat haderech* if someone is traveling on the road and does not ever leave the *techum* (city limits) of one city without entering the *techum* of another (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suburban_sprawl).  Therefore, in the case of an *safek* relating to urban sprawl, people may elect not to omit the benediction entirely, but rather incorporate it into *shomeya tefillah* in the *amidah* of *shacharit*, to avoid both the problem of *bracha levatala* and the problem of its omission due to *safek*.